# Contour Integral of Square root Function. Branch Cuts

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am doing a physics problem and have come across a contour integral that I just don't know how to solve.  I do not have the complex analysis background and I am wondering if anyone can explain how to do it from a beginners perspective.  I have done a lot of research on my own but I am still confused about a few things.

The integral is the following.

\begin{equation}
J=\frac{\sqrt{2m}}{2\pi}\oint \sqrt{X_0-a\sec^2\left( \frac{x}{l} \right)}dx
\end{equation}

My professor says I need to look at "the branch points as well as at infinity."  So I was able to determine that if I write this as a series and take the coefficient of the term with exponent -1, that will be the residue, (Not sure why, again I don't have much expeirence with this stuff.)  and then I can use the residue theorem.  When I did this, I got a residue of $i\sqrt{a}$, meaning the integral should be $\frac{\sqrt{2m}}{2\pi}2\pi i (i\sqrt{a})=-\sqrt{2ma}$.  But this can't be the whole picture as I didn't do anything with branch cuts. (I also know this because I absolutely need an $X_0$ term by virtue of the physics problem I am doing)  I am not even sure what they are honestly.  After reading a few things I determined that they seem to be the location where the function gets defined in a piecewise fashion. But I am confused as to how to use them for evaluating an integral.  I have taken a look at other examples on the internet but I always seem to get confused while going through the process they show.  What will help me the MOST is to solve THIS integral, since it is the one I spent so much time on.

If anyone can help me in any way it would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
I believe I have determined the contour of the problem.  I needed to take into account the positive and negative nature of the square root and I get the following contour (just the center loop)

[image]

Comment: To begin, what are you trying to do?  Are you trying to compute the contour integral as an end or a means to an end?  And if it is an end, what is the contour?

Comment: Well at the end of the day I want to obtain an expression for $J$ that will will be a function of $X_0$.  From here I can solve for $X_0$ in terms of $J$.

As for the contour, that is another aspect that is confusing to me.  The integrand defines a particles momentum, and the problem says the particle is moves along a straight line. If I plot the function, I get a parabolic looking shape that is symmetric about the p (or y) axis.  So I THINK  the contour will be this shape with a straight line connecting the two sides.

Comment: OK...then what is the contour over which you are integrating?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed enter before I was done.  I have edited my first response.

Comment: The particles motion is oscillatory by the way.  So I think it goes back and forth on the line.

Comment: what is the closed loop you are integrating over?

Comment: Furthermore how big is $X_0/a$?